# Is there a collection function like map to turn every item in a list into two items?

Tags: kotlin

Say I have a list of integers, as such:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13)
```

I want to run an operation to create a similar list but with an additional element after every element. For example, we should be able to add a `-99` after each element as such:

`[1, -99, 2, -99, 3, -99, 5, -99, 8, -99, 13, -99]`

I can do this with a forEach loop and temporary list easily, as such:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13)
val tempList = mutableListOf<Int>()
list.forEach {
    tempList.add(it)
    tempList.add(-99)
}
println(tempList) // [1, -99, 2, -99, 3, -99, 5, -99, 8, -99, 13, -99]
```

But this seems unnecessarily verbose and imperative. Another way I found is to map each item to a list with the two elements, creating a list of lists, and flattening the result. Example:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13)
val mapFlatten = list
    .map { listOf(it, -99) }
    .flatten()
 
println(mapFlatten) // [1, -99, 2, -99, 3, -99, 5, -99, 8, -99, 13, -99]
```

However, creating a list of lists and then flattening seems unnecessarily redundant. Is there any list operation that allows us to do this in a simpler way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simplify your second option by using `flatMap` directly:

```kotlin
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13)
val mapFlatten = list.flatMap { listOf(it, -99) }
```

You still have these intermediate lists technically, but I'm not sure it can be simplified further.

If you *really* have huge lists and you're concerned about extra allocations, you could fallback to just building a list manually like you did, unless you're not scared of experimental functions and are ok with `buildList`:

```kotlin
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13)
val mapFlatten = buildList(2 * list.size) {
    list.forEach {
        add(it)
        add(-99)
    }
}
```

Comment: resulting list size is known in advance, so for better performance (memory reallocation avoidance) it could be specified: `buildList(2 * list.size) { ... }`

Comment: @МихаилНафталь TIL `buildList` can take a capacity. Thanks!